# How to make a function return separate arrays according to the input value and pass it to the view in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project where I am calling a list of books from an API and passing it to 3 different categories based on the user selection.So, all the books from the API will be first retrieved in the search page.Each book will have a drop-down select option which will have 3 options for the book:

1. Currently Reading
2. Want to read and
3. Read

. So, on another page, there are these **3 shelves** for each section.So, when the user selects an option from the drop-down, the book will transfer to the respective shelf.And the user can even move the books from one shelf to another shelf according to their experience with the book.
So, currently, I am able to pass the books from the main search page to their shelf.What I am stuck at is **passing the books from one shelf to another**.

**Updated the Code with a separate Component for the Book Shelf:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BookShelf from './CurrentlyReading.js'

class BooksList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        showSearchPage: false,
        books: this.props.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, {status:"none"}))
      };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

  handleChange=(index,event) => {
    let books = this.state.books;
    books[index].status = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ books });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.books !== nextProps.books) {
    this.setState({ books: nextProps.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, { status: "none" })) });
  }
}

  render() {
    const currentlyReading = this.state.books.filter(book => book.status === "currentlyReading");
    console.log(currentlyReading);
    var result = currentlyReading.map(a => a.title);
    console.log(result);

    const wantToRead = this.state.books.filter(book => book.status === "wantToRead");

    const read = this.state.books.filter(book => book.status === "read");

    return(
        <div className="app">
          {this.state.showSearchPage ? (


            <div className="search-books">
              <div className="search-books-bar">
                <a className="close-search" onClick={() => this.setState({ showSearchPage: false })}>Close</a>
                <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">

                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title or author"/>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="search-books-results">
                <ol className="book-search">

                {<div className="book-search">
                  <BookShelf bookDetail={this.state.books} />
              </div>
                }

                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="list-books">
              <div className="list-books-title">
                <h1>MyReads</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="list-books-content">
                <div>
                  <div className="bookshelf">
                    <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Currently Reading</h2>
                    <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      <ol className="books-grid">

                      <BookShelf bookDetail={currentlyReading} />
                      </ol>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div className="bookshelf">
                    <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Want to Read</h2>
                    <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      <ol className="books-grid">


                        <BookShelf bookDetail={wantToRead} />

                      </ol>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bookshelf">
                    <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Read</h2>
                    <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      <ol className="books-grid">

                      <BookShelf bookDetail={read} />

                      </ol>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="open-search">
                <a onClick={() => this.setState({ showSearchPage: true })}>Add a book</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BooksList;


I know I need to make some changes in the `handleChange()` method for the books when they are on the shelf.But I am not sure if I can use the present `handleChange()` method which is getting the values from the search page to the bookshelf or Does I need to create a new `handleChange()` method for moving the books to different shelves.Can anyone please help me with this?

**Edit 1: Created new component and tried passing the array as prop.But I am getting which says "this is a reserved word"**

My code for the component: 

    import React, { Component } from 'react';

        class BookShelf extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }

          render() {
            return(
              { this.props.currentlyReading.map((book,index) =>
                <li>
                  <div className="book">
                    <div className="book-top">
                      <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
                      <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                        <select
                          value={book.status}
                          onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(index,event)}>
                          <option value="none" disabled>&nbsp; &nbsp; Move to...</option>
                          <option value="currentlyReading">&#x2714; Currently Reading</option>
                          <option value="wantToRead">&nbsp; &nbsp; Want to Read</option>
                          <option selected="selected" value="read">&nbsp; &nbsp; Read</option>
                          <option value="none">&nbsp; &nbsp; None</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>{book.status}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                    <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                  </div>
                  </li>
              )}


            );
          }
        }

        export default BookShelf;
```

The new Component for each BookShelf:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BookShelf extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="book-search">
     { this.props.bookDetail.map((book,index)=>
        <li>
          <div className="book">
            <div className="book-top">
              <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
              <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                <select
                  value={book.status}
                  onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(index,event)}>
                  <option value="none" disabled>&nbsp; &nbsp; Move to...</option>
                  <option value="currentlyReading">&#x2714; Currently Reading</option>
                  <option value="wantToRead">&nbsp; &nbsp; Want to Read</option>
                  <option selected="selected" value="read">&nbsp; &nbsp; Read</option>
                  <option value="none">&nbsp; &nbsp; None</option>
                </select>
                <p>{book.status}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
            <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
          </div>
          </li>

      )}
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default BookShelf;
```

**Edit: Added the updated code with the new component for each shelf**

Comment: I'd like to help, but 90% of the above code is irrelevant to the question. You should move your bookshelf code into a separate component, then include that three times. This would remove tons of duplicate code, and also gravely shorten the above component, making the code much more readable and this question much more likely to be answered.

Comment: @Chris okay,I will try to separate it out as 3 different components and update my question again.In the meantime, could you please check and let me know how to proceed with the problem I am facing?

Comment: @Chris I have one doubt.So,if I make a single component for the 3 shelves,how will I render the view for the 3 separate arrays.I mean I have 3 arrays for each shelf.So do I need to pass the array as a prop to the component? I am new to react.So,I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. First you create a `Book` component. Move the book `<div>` to a separate component, then pass all information as props.

Comment: @Chris I have created the component and tried passing the array as props.But I get the error "this is a reserved word". I have posted my code above.Can you please check ?

Comment: My guess is it should be `<BookShelf currentlyReading={currentlyReading} />`

Comment: That didn't work.I am getting the error for the "this" in the BookShelf Component while accessing the Props

Comment: Hi again @pranami. Chris is right, you have to rethink your code with a more modular approach. Properly designing your components is a critical part of React, and must be done before you even write a single line of code. In your case, it's pretty obvious you want to have a parent BooksList component, composed of one BookSearch component and several Bookshelf components (one for each status a book might be in), and finally have each Bookshelf composed of as many Book components as there are books on that particular shelf. With the proper design you'll find actual coding flows naturally.

Comment: Found the problem: you need `return (<ul>{ this.props.map(...) }</ul>);` You have `{ ... }` which creates an Object literal, and you can't use `this` as key.

Comment: Helloo @Jaxx , great to hear from you again :) Okay,I will try to modularize the code.Actually that's what I was trying to do as Chris suggested.But again I stumbled upon an error. And thanks again for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah,its working now.That was the issue.Thanks for the correction.I will try to update the question above with the new code.Please let me know how do I proceed after that?

Comment: @Jaxx would you mind to check up on my new issue again today? ;P I am stcuk again with moving the books within the shelf .

Comment: @pranami I'm not going to write all your code for you, but here's what I'll do. I'll write an answer with a suggested component architecture, and then you can work on the detailed implementation (and if you encounter specific problems we can work on those individually).

Comment: @Jaxx yeah,sure.We can proceed the way you suggested.Actually I wrote the code for the New component and imported it to the previous component .But the problem I am facing now is while trying to move the book from one shelf to another .So,the book moves from the main list to the shelf but if I want to move it from say "Currently Reading" to "Read",how do I design the handleChange function?That's where I am stuck now.The previous handleChange isn't working for this case.

Comment: @pranami I ended up writing much of the code, but you'll still have to understand it and hook it up to your project. Let me know how this goes, and if you have questions about what I've done and why, I encourage you to ask.

Comment: @Jaxx Yeah,I will try to go through the code and let you know if I don't get any part.Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a separate file like `consts.js`:

```
const SHELVES = ['None', 'Currently reading', 'Want to read', 'Read'];
module.exports = { SHELVES };
```

Top component BooksList:

```
import { SHELVES } from './consts';
import BookShelf from './BookShelf';
import BookSearch from './BookSearch';

class BooksList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      books: []
    };
  }
  // given a shelf-less books array, set shelf to default for all books
  setDefaultShelf = (books) => {
    this.setState({ books: books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, {shelf: SHELVES[0]});
  }
  // todo: search function handler
  doSearch = (search) => {
    // API call here, should call this.setDefaultShelf with books data when it has returned
  }
  // shelf selection handler
  chooseShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    let { books } = this.state;
    books.find(b => b === book).shelf = shelf;
    this.setState({ books });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BookSearch doSearch={this.doSearch} />
        <div className="bookshelves">
          {SHELVES.map((shelf, index) => {
            return (
              <BookShelf
                key={index}
                shelf={shelf}
                books={this.state.books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelf)}
                chooseShelf={this.chooseShelf}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

BookShelf component:

```
import Book from './Book';

const BookShelf = ({ shelf, books, chooseShelf }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bookshelf">
      <h2>{shelf}</h2>
      <ul>
      {books.map((book, index) => {
        return (
          <Book
            key={index}
            book={book}
            chooseShelf={chooseShelf}
          />
        );
      })}
      </ul>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Book component:

```
import { SHELVES } from './consts';

const Book = ({ book, chooseShelf }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div className="book">
        <div className="book-top">
          <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
          <div className="book-shelf-changer">
            <select
              value={book.shelf}
              onChange={(event) => chooseShelf(book, event.target.value)}>
              {SHELVES.map(shelf => {
                return(<option value={shelf} selected={shelf === book.shelf ? "selected" : ""}>{shelf}</option>);
              })} 
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
        <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

You'd still have to define & create the BookSearch component and hook it to the API through the parent doSearch method, add module.exports for all components, proper React import statements, etc. but the gist of it is here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constant effort in each step. I will go through the code you provided and try to get all the modules together.Thanks once again :)

Comment: @pranami You're welcome. More than the code itself, it's critical that you understand this modular structure, and how components relate to one another. It's really the core of React. Feel free to get back to me if you have any questions ;)

Comment: surely will get back to you as I did today ;)

Comment: @pranami I've just made a few critical edits, make sure you work on the latest version of my code.

Comment: I have few questions.1) where does the find() method come from in chooseSelf?I mean I cannot see it defined anywhere?So,is this a pre-defined function? 2)And I just want to clarify if what I understand about the "shelf" array is the right one.Just correct me if I am wrong.So, the shelf variable is set to none at the beginning right.Then you  pass the value of event.target.value to shelf in onChange which is the value for chooseSelf which ultimately is the value for the 2nd line in the chooseShelf method.But I am not getting what is going on in that line. Can you please explain a lil bit

Comment: 1. find is a built-in Array method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find ; it returns the first value in the array that satisfies the test conditions. In this case, it returns the book whose shelf we want to modify. 2. Yes, you are correct. What that line does is (a) find the book, using the find method (see 1. above) in the books array that matches the book parameter passed to the function and (b) sets the shelf value for that book to the shelf parameter also passed to the function.

Comment: ohh,okay.that's cool.The first time I saw the code,most of the things just bounced over my head ;P I wish coding was as easy for me as you make it sound.You explain the things so well ,I feel like even a newbie like me can get through it.But the moment I start to tackle the problems,that's when the real struggle comes. ;) Great,I will try to get through the rest of the code and merge the other parts. Thanks man.You rock!!!